# Download Files with Python using a submit Button

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, automation, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As the title implies, I would like to use Python to download a file using a submit button.
In my example its a pdf file from Wikipedia.

It's easy to find answers on how to download files from URLs ending with .png or something. I wasn't able to find much about my specific problem though.

A sample page would look like [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:ElectronPdf&page=Rektifikationskolonne&action=show-download-screen).
By clicking the button the download starts and the file is saved to your Downloads folder.
How can I realize this process with Python? I tried different packages like `requests`, `bs4` or `urllib`.

I do not want to solve the problem by using pyautogui or something to literally 'click' the button by using its position on the screen, I'd rather have a solution that is able to operate in the background.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Selenium web driver is probably your best bet

Comment: I found a way to solve the problem. Using the chrome developer tools I was able to view the URL you are getting redirected to on submit (button click). This said I was able to understand the URLs structure, which was in general just using the basic ASCII (%) encoding.

I will finish my code tommorow I guess. If someone is interested in this for testing purposes or something else I can post it here ofc.

For now I can post the pdf's URL if you want to investigate on your own: https://de.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/pdf/ <ENCODED ARTICLE GOES HERE>

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium and then click on download button with code